# Can I add browser add-ons like uBlock Origin to Android WebView or GeckoView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, webview, firefox-addon-webextensions, geckoview

Is it doable to include browser extensions like uBlock Origin into Android WebView or GeckoView when developing with Android Studio? I'd like to understand the compatibility and feasibility of such integration

I've attempted to utilize WebView and have also experimented with manual integration methods, all in an effort to include browser extensions like uBlock Origin. Unfortunately, my efforts so far have not yielded successful results. Given my limited experience in this area.

Comment: See https://github.com/wuruxu/crwebview

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.